# How to manage contacts using Contacts API in our website correctly?

Tags: google-authentication, google-contacts-api

I was trying to integrate Google Contacts API to manage the contacts in my website.

I've done the following things:

1. I've created an application in google developer console and added `http://localhost:4200` as URIs & Authorized redirect URIs.
2. Enabled 'Contacts API'.
3. I've added the following in my `index.html` (I've replaced `{clientID}` with my original client ID (of course):

```
  <script>
    function loadAuthClient() {
      gapi.load('auth2', function() {
        gapi.auth2.init({
          client_id: '{clientID}'
        }).then(() => {
          console.log("success");
        }).catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
      });
    }
  </script>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=loadAuthClient" async defer></script>
  <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="{clientID}">
```

4. Signed in successfully using:

```
    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn().then(() => {
      console.log("Logged in")
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

4. Tried fetching the contacts using the following:

```
    var user = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get();
    var idToken = user.getAuthResponse().id_token;
    var endpoint = `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/`;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', endpoint + '?access_token=' + encodeURIComponent(idToken));
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Gdata-Version", "3.0");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {
        window.alert(xhr.responseText);
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
```

But I'm getting the error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/?access_token={I removed the access token}' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Can someone please guide me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: It wasn't obvious to me that you meant "Authorized JavaScript origins" in step 1. It isn't mentioned so you may want to update your question with it.

Answer (score 0):

My original response was off the mark. The actual answer is much simpler.

In step 4, try changing your endpoint:

```
var endpoint = `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full`;
```

In my local tests, this resulted in the expected response.

Another suggestion is to add `alt=json` to your query, so that you get easy to parse JSON payload. Otherwise you'll get a nasty XML payload in the response.

Here's the updated step 4 with these changes:

```
var endpoint = `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full`;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', endpoint + '?access_token=' + encodeURIComponent(idToken) + '&alt=json');
xhr.setRequestHeader("Gdata-Version", "3.0");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {
    window.alert(xhr.responseText);
  }
};
xhr.send();
```

---

Here's my original response, just in case it helps someone else.

I suspect that you'll need to add `http://localhost:4200` to your list of "Authorized JavaScript origins" for the OAuth Client that you are using.

Edit your [OAuth 2.0 Client ID](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) and add the URI to the Javascript origins as below:
[image: OAuth client with a Javascript origin]

The other section on that page, Authorized Redirect URIs, only permits the OAuth flow to be redirected back to your web app. Often your web app server will actually consume the APIs so Google doesn't automatically permit CORS access to these APIs to keep things secure.

Comment: Hi Graeme, I've done that already (as mentioned in my step 1). I've even tried adding it in only one place where you said. But sadly both aren't working for me.

Comment: @Grovile I updated my answer after looking more carefully at your code. Thanks for the detailed question, I was able to point out the issue now.